# Move vanity location and far away from plumbing

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, remodeling, vanity

I am remodeling the bathroom and the old vanity was on the left side of the wall

[image]

The old vanity was only 24" wide so I want to make it longer by turning it side way to the back wall so I can fit a 60" vanity:

[image]

I have to put the sink far the right side because the left side is next to the toilet.

My questions are:

1. The drain is going to be far away. Is it OK to have the sink about 3-4 ft away from the drain like that?
2. The left side of the vanity will be drawers or cabinets. I think the door will hit the toilet. Is there a way (or idea) to work around that?

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**

This is the old layout of my 7.5x9.5 bathroom

[image]

Old photos

[image]

Here is my proposed layout

[image]

The main changes are:

1. Move door to the right a bit to accommodate longer shower space
2. Curbless shower
3. Bigger vanity on the back wall instead

Comment: From a Form-Fit-Function point of view, you note 2 would-be show stoppers: 1. Drawers cant close, pipe behind them, drawer cannot open, toilet in front of them. You mentioned you dont want to rip down walls, but that is the "best" way to do what you want. Move the toilet is another. You can get some very interesting drawers where they fold open, and are short depth, but again, function is more than hindered. You can buy some interesting "in wall" toilets. But these suggestions aren't cheap, and might take some real planning. Good luck.

Comment: What about the drain location concern? Would it slow the drain?
I think for #2, I could do tall wall cabinet facing the right. Then I can get 48" vanity or something.

Comment: as long as you have the correct slope, you can make it work, but I believe the code on a bathroom 1.25 pipe is like 2.5 feet. So ideally, you'd want to move the vent pipe. (while "it may work" it very well will work less than ideally).

Comment: The 48” vanity and a tall cabinet is a decent solution; better and more practical than the 5’ vanity.

Comment: I am starting to think 48" wide might be better. Although I like it better if there is a 60" floating (wall mount) so I can get over the toilet blocking in the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a clearance between vanity and toilet of 15" measured from the center of the toilet towards the side

You can relocate the plumbing toward the left side of the wall and install the vanity sink there. You can have the drawers on the opposite side to make possible to have them open

Answer (score 0):

I would rethink your bathroom design. A large vanity may not be your best option given the size of the room, toilet proximity, etc.

You may want to consider a corner pedestal and an upright shelving/drawer system instead. Lots of options other than a long vanity with semi-blocked drawers.

Staying closer to the original plumbing outlets make plumbing concerns simpler, less expensive and more likely to work well.

People often choose a vanity over a pedestal sink because of storage and counter space. Ultimately, a vanity is a large piece of furniture going into a relatively small space. If you use a 48” vanity it is a better fit but it still takes up more floor room than a corner pedestal and shelving/cabinet option and requires more plumbing modifications.

Your concern about the sink being so close to the toilet is noted. With a corner install, the sink is away from toilet (nearly as much as with a 48” vanity), and creates much more actual and visual floor and wall space for a less crowded feeling. A corner med cab can be installed as well to provide storage.

I offer these suggestions based on my years of bathroom remodels.

[image: corner pedestal]

Comment: This is not an option. This bathroom is huge and everything is jammed up on the left side, leaving 2/3 on the right side empty.

Comment: If you post a couple of photos of the whole bathroom space to give perspective and the dimensions, I will give you some different options. I remodeled bathrooms for over ten years.

Comment: I have updated the question with more details.

Comment: Alrighty then. It’s not ideal having the washer/dryer in the bathroom, obviously. That said, have you considered framing out a wall and creating a separate laundry space? Easier than moving the door as it wouldn’t be load bearing. I’m gonna think on this and I’ll be back and add suggestions. Truly, this could be a great space.

Comment: My opinion, the shower is in the wrong place. The spot where the toilet and proposed vanity would go or are, is where the tub/spa/shower should be. The toilet where the proposed basin is as a better location vs. current, and then the entire front wall (next to the door) is ready for a vanity, mirrors, in wall cabinets, etc. The washer dryer can stay where proposed but a wall would be a nice approch. This corner could be built to have a corner cabinet/closet, and still have stacked units, but the space would be very cramped at that point.